# how to add empty fragment with LeanBack android tv

Tags: android, fragment, android-tv, leanback

I didn't know what should I wrote as title . I tried to explain what I want . I am working on android tv project and I am using LeanBack library . I want to add an activity with fragment to add some customize ui . My goal is something like sample picture. I know how I could add this row but I don't know how add fragment . If I want to explain in other way . I want to have a browseFragment without header .If I use `setHeadersState(HEADERS_DISABLED)` or `setHeadersState(HEADERS_HIDDEN)`  it didn't help me because there is a relevant between row and header . i just want to have the row nothing more .

[image]

this is my code to add fragment but I got error .
firstActivity:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
}
}
```

fragment :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;

 import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
 import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.leanback.widget.ArrayObjectAdapter;
import androidx.leanback.widget.ClassPresenterSelector;
 import androidx.leanback.widget.ListRow;
import androidx.leanback.widget.ListRowPresenter;


 public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {


private ArrayObjectAdapter categoryAdapter;


@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}


private void setupCategoryRow(){
    ///some code here
    addCategoriesRow();
}


//
private void addCategoriesRow(){
    ArrayObjectAdapter categoryListAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(new GridItemPresenter());

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        categoryListAdapter.add("test");
    }
    categoryAdapter.add(categoryListAdapter);

}
 }
```

error :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: //.com, PID: 31366
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{//com.ui.FirstActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at 
    android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error 
  inflating class fragment
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment //.com.ui.FirstFragment did not create 
    a view.
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManagerImpl.java:3234)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:134)
    at 
    androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:357)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:336)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:694)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:160)
    at //.com.ui.FirstActivity.onCreate(FirstActivity.java:16)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
    android.view.InflateException: 
     Binary 
    XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at 
     android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: 
     Error 
     inflating class fragment
      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class 
      fragment
      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment //.com.ui.FirstFragment did not 
     create 
     a view.
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManagerImpl.java:3234)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:134)
    at 
     androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:357)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:336)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:694)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:160)
    at //.com.ui.FirstActivity.onCreate(FirstActivity.java:16)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at 
    android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Can you provide a picture to explain what you want to achieve ? And if you want to work with ``leanback``, use ``FragmentActivity`` with ``Theme.Leanback`` theme

Comment: Hi , I forget to add picture . now add it .

Comment: You want to add ``Fragment`` into Horizontal list like the image (Blue one is ``Fragment`` ?)

Comment: No , blue one is customized GridItemPresenter  .

Comment: I edited photo to make it more clear.

Comment: So you want a screen without ``BrowseSupportFragment`` header right ?
Then you have to use a ``Fragment`` and wrap a ``RowsSupportFragment``. You can check ``DetailsSupportFragment`` to know how to do that.